# Debugging nil optionals

Tags: swift

Numerously in the past I have fixed the sporadic `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error, and I have just fixed one now; However the way I am doing it right now is through guessing where the nil optionals are via breakpoints.

There is **always** an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` under `Swift._fatalErrorMessage` (in the assembly) when an error like this is thrown for me.

*Is there a more efficient method* (like a exception catch) *of jumping to the nil optional instead of guessing where it is with log messages and (inline) breakpoints?*

Answer (score 0):

Your crashes are almost certainly happening in a line where you're forcibly unwrapping an optional using `!`. Unless you're absolutely certain that a value exists, you should use `if let` instead.

Instead of:

```
let myValue = myArray[index]!  // will crash if myArray[index] is nil
```

Use this:

```
if let myValue = myArray[index] {
  println("myValue has a value and it is \(myValue)")
  // Code using myValue
} else {
  println("myValue is nil")
}
```

Edit: To answer your question directly, search for instances of `!` and in general, replace them with `if let` or `?`.

Comment: I already know why the crashes are happening but I am asking how I can debug this faster than what you have already suggested. Lazily replacing force unwraps is not something I want to do because I have uses for them.

Comment: Understood. Hopefully someone else can answer your question.